# order of files unix find on two directories with or command

Tags: linux, bash, unix

What is the expected order of the files if one executes the following `find` command on Linux:

```
mkdir /tmp/dir1 /tmp/dir2
touch /tmp/dir1/1 /tmp/dir1/2 /tmp/dir2/1 /tmp/dir2/2 /tmp/dir2/3 /tmp/dir2/0
find /tmp/dir1 /tmp/dir2 -name 1 -or -name 0 -not -name 2

/tmp/dir1/1
/tmp/dir2/1
/tmp/dir2/0
```

Is it supposed to always give the results back from dir1 first, then dir2, or can the results be mixed in order?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The find command will search the directories in the order given. Since you said

```
find /tmp/dir1 /tmp/dir2 .....
```

it will always first find evrything that matches below /tmp/dir1, then /tmp/dir2.

Yet, subdirectories and files can, of course, appear in any order.